# What is the best gas efficient way to reset all values for keys in a mapping?

Tags: solidity, mapping

As far as I understand there is no way to automatically reset all values of a mapping to default in solidity. now lets say I have a mapping mapping with 7 keys and values set. to refresh all the values to zero is it better to use a loop or doing it manually like this:

```
mapping(uint256 => uint256) public Vals;
Vals[1] = Vals[2] = Vals[3] = Vals[4] = Vals[5] = Vals[6] = Vals[7] = 0;
```

Manually setting all the values to zero or using a for loop to do this? which way is more gas efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it out and found out that the loop will cost more gas, the one you mentioned costs less gas

```
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public Vals;

    function set() external {
        for (uint256 i; i <= 7; ++i) {
            Vals[i] = 2;
        }
    }

    function deleteWithoutLoop() external {
        Vals[1] = Vals[2] = Vals[3] = Vals[4] = Vals[5] = Vals[6] = Vals[7] = 0;
        //transaction cost - 45458
        //execution cost -   35758
    }

    function deleteWithLoop() external {
        for (uint256 i; i <= 7; ++i) {
            Vals[i] = 0;
            //trasaction cost - 50672
            //execution cost -  42275
        }
    }
}
```